# Images coming out smaller than usual! Android-Java Development

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm making an application to showcase a company's photos, I have created an ImageView within a Relative Layout and Also made it so the user can swipe through the images one by one. However, it all looks ok in Eclipse (with the imageview matching the parent, etc) But when I run it on the emulator or on my device the image comes out tiny! What am I doing wrong?

Here's my XML for the page:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Wedding" 
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And Here is my Java Class:

```
package com.example.ijazphotography;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class Wedding extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wedding);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private int[] mImages = new int[] {
            R.drawable.wed11,
            R.drawable.wed15,
            R.drawable.wed16,
            R.drawable.wed17,
            R.drawable.wed2,
            R.drawable.wed20,
            R.drawable.wed23,
            R.drawable.wed24,
            R.drawable.wed4,
            R.drawable.wed5,
            R.drawable.wed6,
            R.drawable.wed7
        };

        public int getCount() {
            return mImages.length;
        }

        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = Wedding.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

            int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.dimen.padding_medium);
            imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
          }
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object     object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
          }
  }
}
```

Comment: try using `ScaleType.FIT_XY`.

Comment: This works! Thank you very much, would this also work for ImageButtons too? @HamidShatu

Comment: @BilalHaider...I have answered your question in the answer option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE
```

use

```
ScaleType.FIT_XY
```

to fit the image in the `ImageView`.

As you ask, will ScaleType.FIT_XY work for `ImageButton` or not?  Yeah, it will also work for `ImageButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't those widths and height settings be "fill_parent" not "match_parent"?

Comment: Thats what I thought, but I've read that they're both the same thing. Unless I read some utter nonsense? Lol @Agnes

Comment: No, you're right. I'm out of date. match_parent is the right one to use.